# Do these MySQL SELECT queries represent different inner joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [which query is better and efficient - mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138742/which-query-is-better-and-efficient-mysql)

What's the difference, if any, between these two (MySQL) SELECT queries?

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM employee, info
WHERE employee.id = info.id;

SELECT e.name AS name, i.salary AS salary
FROM employee AS e
INNER JOIN info AS i
ON e.id = i.id;
```

Both represent an (the same?) inner join on the tables `employee` and `info`.

Comment: You can find many discussion on this subject : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138742/which-query-is-better-and-efficient-mysql/3138863

Comment: Yes duplicate, I also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-versus-where-clause-any-difference. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes both represents `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT e.name AS name, i.salary AS salary
FROM employee AS e
INNER JOIN info AS i
ON e.id = i.id;
```

is `"explicit join notation"` uses the JOIN keyword to specify the table to join, and the ON keyword to specify the predicates for the join.

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM employee, info
WHERE employee.id = info.id;
```

The `"implicit join notation"` simply lists the tables for joining (in the FROM clause of the SELECT statement), using commas to separate them. Thus, it specifies a `cross join`, and the WHERE clause may apply additional filter-predicates (which function comparably to the join-predicates in the explicit notation).

Check out this example : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join

Comment: Just a note: in MySQL `cross join` and `inner join` are synonyms.