# WHERE clause better execute before IN and JOIN or after

Tags: sql-server

I read this article:
[Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

in end of article has been write ON and JOIN clause consider before WHERE.

Consider we have a master table that has 10 million records and a detail table (that has reference to master table(FK)) with 50 million record. We have a query that want just 100 record of detail table according a PK in master table.

In this situation ON and JOIN execute before WHERE?I mean that do we have 500 million record after JOIN and then WHERE apply to it?or first WHERE apply and then JOIN and ON Consider? If second answer is true do it has incoherence  with top article?

thanks

Comment: The key word is "logical". This is not what SQL Server actually does! Your link says "Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list."

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It doesn't matter

Logical processing order is always honoured: regardless of actual processing order

INNER JOINs and WHERE conditions are effectively associative and commutative (hence the ANSI-89 "join in the where" syntax) so actual order doesn't matter

Logical order becomes important with outer joins and more complex queries: applying WHERE on an OUTER table changes the logic completely.

Again, it doesn't matter how the optimiser does it internally so long as the query semantics are maintained by following logical processing order.

And the key word here is "optimiser": it does exactly what it says

Comment: What about index column orders? Do you suggest that the performance for the order in index ([WHERE condition], [JOIN condition]) be the same as ([JOIN condition], [WHERE condition])?

Comment: @sotn: it depends on selectivity of each column. Sometimes, you have to try both to see which works best.

Answer (score 48):

In the case of an INNER JOIN or a table on the left in a LEFT JOIN, in many cases, the optimizer will find that it is better to perform any filtering first (highest selectivity) before actually performing whatever type of physical join - so there are obviously physical order of operations which are better.

To some extent you can sometimes control this (or interfere with this) with your SQL, for instance, with aggregates in subqueries.

The logical order of processing the constraints in the query can only be transformed according to known invariant transformations.

So:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.something = something
    AND b.something = something
```

is still logically equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.id
    AND a.something = something
    AND b.something = something
```

and they will generally have the same execution plan.

On the other hand:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.something = something
    AND b.something = something
```

is NOT equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.id
    AND a.something = something
    AND b.something = something
```

and so the optimizer isn't going to transform them into the same execution plan.

The optimizer is very smart and is able to move things around pretty successfully, including collapsing views and inline table-valued functions as well as even pushing things down through certain kinds of aggregates fairly successfully.

Typically, when you write SQL, it needs to be understandable, maintainable and correct.  As far as efficiency in execution, if the optimizer is having difficulty turning the declarative SQL into an execution plan with acceptable performance, the code can sometimes be simplified or appropriate indexes or hints added or broken down into steps which *should* perform more quickly - all in successive orders of invasiveness.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your `LEFT JOIN` example. Why is it not equivalent? does the `WHERE` apply to the result of the join?

Comment: @Toskan In the latter, a row will be returned with NULL values for `b` fields if `a.id = b.id`, `a.something = something` or `b.something = something` evaluate to false; in the former, a row will not be returned if `a.something = something` or `b.something = something` evaluate to false.

Comment: @MattArnold oh thanks. So in short: `left join b ON a.id = b.id` will always return something as long as there is rows in a. Basically `left join b ON a.id = b.id` is like saying "it would be nice if you match with `b.id` but if you cannot match, just return `a` and an empty dummy for `b` whereas the `where` obliges to only return if `a.id` and `b.id` match

Comment: @Toskan That's correct, all the fields of `b` will just appear as NULL if no match could be found.

Comment: For @Toskan and future readers whom might have trouble understaindg the `LEFT JOIN` example , see [SQL JOIN - WHERE clause vs. ON clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20981676/5983841)

Answer (score 10):

Just re-reading Paul White's [excellent series on the Query Optimiser](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/07/inside-the-optimiser-constructing-a-plan.html) and remembered this question.

It is possible to use an undocumented command to disable specific transformation rules and get some insight into the transformations applied.

#### For (hopefully!) obvious reasons only try this on a development instance and remember to re-enable them and remove any suboptimal plans from the cache.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008;

/*Disable the rules*/
DBCC RULEOFF ('SELonJN');
DBCC RULEOFF ('BuildSpool');


 SELECT  P.ProductNumber, 
         P.ProductID, 
        I.Quantity
 FROM    Production.Product P
 JOIN    Production.ProductInventory I
         ON  I.ProductID = P.ProductID
WHERE I.ProductID < 3
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

You can see with those two rules disabled it does a cartesian join and filter after.

[image: Rules Off Plan]

```
/*Re-enable them*/   
DBCC RULEON ('SELonJN');
DBCC RULEON ('BuildSpool');

 SELECT  P.ProductNumber, 
         P.ProductID, 
        I.Quantity
 FROM    Production.Product P
 JOIN    Production.ProductInventory I
         ON  I.ProductID = P.ProductID
WHERE I.ProductID < 3
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

With them enabled the predicate is pushed right down into the index seek and so reduces the number of rows processed by the join operation.

[image: Rules on Plan]

Comment: Link is Broken :(

Comment: @YousufIqbalHashim moved to https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/07/inside-the-optimiser-constructing-a-plan.html

Answer (score 6):

There is no defined order. The SQL engine determines what order to perform the operations based on the execution strategy chosen by its optimizer.

Comment: There is a logical order that is honoured, no matter what order is actually used in practice

Answer (score 2):

I think you have misread `ON` as `IN` in the article.

However, the order it is showing in the article is correct (obviously it is msdn anyway). The `ON` and `JOIN` are executed before `WHERE` naturally because `WHERE` has to be applied as a filter on the temporary resultset obtained due to `JOINS`

The article just says it is logical order of execution and also at end of the paragraph it adds this line too ;)

*"Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this list."*