# In SQLAlchemy, is a filter applied before or after a join?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy, I'm performing queries like the one below:

```
import models as m
import sqlalchemy as sa

s = session_maker()
q = s.query(m.ShareCount, m.Article)
.join(m.Article)
.filter(sa.and_(start < m.ShareCount.tstamp, m.ShareCount.tstamp < end))
```

Is the `filter` applied before or after the `join` is performed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is, apparently, it depends.

@univerio is correct, the sqlalchemy filter does simply translate to a where, but the actual execution plan for the query may be arranged so that the filter is applied first. It just depends on the query and the optimizer's implementation.

I found [this answer regarding the SQL order of operations for WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5463482/2602816) to be most helpful in understanding this.

Comment: Like the accepted answer says in that question, the logical order is `JOIN` then `WHERE`. It's not usually useful to talk about the physical order of the query plan unless you are doing query optimization. Sometimes it doesn't even make sense to talk about the order because the `WHERE` clause and the `JOIN` clause can be combined by the query planner into a single join of some sort.

Comment: Query optimization is the motive for my question

Comment: If query planning is your motive then you have to look at the query with something like `explain analyze` (for PostgreSQL for example). But there's no way to know how a database is going to handle your query.

Comment: @DaveHalter Thank you for rephrasing exactly what I found to be the solution

Answer (score 4):

> Is the filter applied before or after the join is performed?

It does not really matter if the filter is applied before a join. SQLAlchemy will probably put the join before the filter, because that's how SQL typically looks like.

However the query optimization engines in a database are responsible for optimization. On PostgreSQL for example you can take your query and put an `explain analyze` before it to understand better what's happening.

In general it's quite hard to predict how a query is going to behave in different database systems. PostgreSQL and MySQL have different optimization techniques, so the query plans will look different as well.

My suggestion is: Don't optimize. Databases are extremely cool technology that mostly do the right thing. If something is slow, it's most likely because you forgot to add an index. If you are working with 100 million+ rows you might start to hit limitations where you might start worrying about how your queries execute. However I doubt that you are at that point.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `JOIN` happens before `WHERE`. In SQLAlchemy

```
session.query(Foo).join(Bar).filter(baz)
```

translates to

```
SELECT * FROM Foo JOIN Bar ON ... WHERE baz;
```

Comment: Why the down votes on this one? It's just missing "Logically..." from the beginning.