# Normal Join vs Join with Subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

What is the best way for query with joins?

1. First join tables and then add where conditions
2. First add where conditions with subquery and then join

For example which one of the following queries have a better performance?

```
select * from person persons
         inner join role roles on roles.person_id_fk = persons.id_pk 
         where roles.deleted is null
```

or

```
select * from person persons
         inner join (select * from role roles where roles.deleted is null) as roles
         on roles.person_id_fk = persons.id_pk
```

Comment: The first version should perform better, because it avoids an explicit subquery.  For educational purposes, you should run `EXPLAIN` on both of these queries to see for yourself how Postgres would evaluate each one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WHERE clause better execute before IN and JOIN or after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463101/where-clause-better-execute-before-in-and-join-or-after)

Comment: @Bawpotter No I want the best way for join but this question is about order of query execution.

Comment: I would be very surprised if there was any difference. I am pretty sure the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) will be identical for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a decent database, there should be no difference between the two queries.  Remember, SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.  That is, a SQL `SELECT` statement describes the result set that should be returned.  It does not specify the steps for creating it.

Your two queries are semantically equivalent and the SQL optimizer should be able to recognize that.

Of course, SQL optimizers are not omniscient.  So, sometimes how you write a query *does* affect the execution plan.  However, the queries that you are describing are turned into execution plans that have no concept of "subquery", so it is reasonable that they would produce the same execution plan.

Note:  Some databases -- such as MySQL and MS Access -- do not have very good optimizers and such queries do produce different execution plans.  Alas.