# WHERE Versus AND

Tags: sql

I am trying to determine if I should use WHERE, or AND, or if it matters:

```
FROM table1

LEFT OUTER JOIN table3
ON --------

JOIN table2 
ON --------
AND -------
AND --------
AND year = ii_year
```

For the last line I can also use the following:
    WHERE year = ii_year and I get the same results.
Which should I use?
Thank you
I actually do have a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause

All answers are subset of this thread(including its outgoing links ;)). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming MySQL for this answer).

If it's an `INNER JOIN`, like on your example, it makes no difference. But if you use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and put the conditions in the `WHERE` clause, it will behave like an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I actually do have a LEFT OUTER JOIN directly under the FROM and then a couple INNER JOINS after.  So are you saying that because there is a LEFT OUTER JOIN first, that anything in a following WHERE clause will no longer act as a LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: @doug: Something like `SELECT * FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id WHERE b.type = 'A'` will essentially function as an `INNER JOIN`, because a row in the result-set can never satisfy the `b.type = 'A'` condition unless the join succeeded. But something like `SELECT * FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id WHERE a.type = 'B'` is absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks @ruakh, nice examples!

Answer (score 3):

In query execution order `JOIN` executed before `WHERE` condition filtering, so join conditions are some kind of pre-filtering of the result set.

For `INNER JOIN` this does not make any difference, but for `OUTER` (LEFT/RIGHT) does.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, `AND` is the logical operator for when two conditions in a `WHERE` statement **must** return `true` to be valid. This is the correct syntax:

```
SELECT column
FROM table
JOIN othertable ON ...
WHERE (column > 10) AND (column2 < 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking if you should write queries like this:

```
SELECT
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.year = table2.year;
```

Versus:

```
SELECT
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.year = table2.year;
```

There is no difference, logically speaking. And most parsers / query engines will treat them as identical. The rule of thumb I use is this:

- If the comparison condition is being used in order to **relate** two entities, place that in a `JOIN` clause
- If the comparison is instead being used to **filter** the result set, place that in a `WHERE` clause

I find that those two rules keep the intent of the query more clear. In your specific example, I'd need more information to really decide which category it falls into.

Comment: That is absolutely *not* what the OP is asking. Both of the OP's query variants use ANSI joins.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE`, save the `ON` keyword for joining tables. It's by far more readable, and won't give you undesired result when using `OUTER JOIN`...

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, the difference is that `ON` clauses indicate the conditions that relate the two tables (e.g. `ON table2.table1id = table1.id AND table2.is_active = 'Y'`), whereas `WHERE` clauses indicate conditions that determine which rows you actually want (e.g. `WHERE table1.name LIKE 'Foo %' AND table1.type = 3`).

But this difference, as you've observed, as no effect when you're using an `INNER JOIN`; it only affects the query results if you have a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or whatnot (where a failed condition in the `ON` clause means that you omit data from `table2`, whereas a failed condition in the `WHERE` clause means that you filter out entire rows from your result-set).

So when you're using an `INNER JOIN`, you just have to decide which way seems like a more intuitive way to think about a certain condition. There's not always a single "right" answer.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use a `WHERE` clause for the last one.  Then you are using the `ANDs` for the fields that are joining the tables and the `WHERE` for the filtering.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
   AND t1.field2 = t2.field2
   AND t1.field3 = t2.field3
WHERE year = ii_year
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance they seem quite similar but they aren’t.  Joining with multiple conditions can result in a different dataset than joining and filtering (where statement).

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM customer
JOIN order ON customer.id = order.customerid
WHERE customer.id = 10
```

Will return all orders for customer ID 10

```
SELECT * FROM customer
JOIN order ON customer.id = order.customerid AND order.id = 10
```

Will return ALL customers but only order details for customer 10 will be joined, the rest will be blank (depending on join method used)

If you’re using INNER JOIN then yes you can use either and the SQL optimiser will change the query for the best execution plan.

If you’re using OUTER JOIN then the returned dataset will contain all customers, every customer apart from id = 10 will have NULL entries