# Eclipselink extend JOIN clause

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

The current code:

```
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(MinutisPreke.class);
Root<MinutisPreke> from = criteriaQuery.from(MinutisPreke.class);
Join<LankomumasDiena, MinutisPreke> ld = from.join("lankomumasDiena", JoinType.LEFT);
cb.and(cb.equal(ld.get("intervalas"), 7));
```

generates the following query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(t0.pr_id) FROM preke AS t0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN lankomumas AS t1 
ON (t1.pr_id = t0.pr_id) 
WHERE (t1.intervalas = 7)
```

How to add statement in the LEFT OUTER JOIN **ON** clause using **criteria query** so my code would generate this query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(t0.pr_id) FROM preke AS t0 
LEFT OUTER JOIN lankomumas AS t1 
ON (t1.pr_id = t0.pr_id) AND (t1.intervalas = 7)
```

**EDIT 1:**
If you don't see any difference in first and second querys, please read this thread:
[SQL join: where clause vs. on clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EclipseLink added support for the ON clause in a 2.5 nightly build as described here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367452
but it is not a part of the JPA specification so you will need to cast the Join to EclipseLink's org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.JoinImpl

```
((JoinImpl)ld).on(cb.and(cb.equal(ld.get("intervalas"), 7));
```

Comment: Is it safe to use nightly build?