# Understanding the difference between ON with multiple conditions and WHERE in a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will list some queries. Outputs are given later, towards the end.

This query gives me 7 rows.

```
SELECT
S.companyname AS supplier, S.country,
P.productid, P.productname, P.unitprice
FROM Production.Suppliers AS S
LEFT OUTER JOIN Production.Products AS P
ON S.supplierid = P.supplierid
WHERE S.country = N'Japan'
ORDER BY S.country
```

The next query is the same as above except that WHERE is replaced by AND. This gives 34 
rows.

```
SELECT
S.companyname AS supplier, S.country,
P.productid, P.productname, P.unitprice
FROM Production.Suppliers AS S
LEFT OUTER JOIN Production.Products AS P
ON S.supplierid = P.supplierid
AND S.country = N'Japan'
ORDER BY S.country
```

I don't understand how why the output for second query is as shown below. Please explain.

---

Output 1  -

```
supplier            country productid   productname unitprice
Supplier QOVFD  Japan   9           Product AOZBW   97.00
Supplier QOVFD  Japan   10          Product YHXGE   31.00
Supplier QOVFD  Japan   74          Product BKAZJ   10.00
Supplier QWUSF  Japan   13          Product POXFU   6.00
Supplier QWUSF  Japan   14          Product PWCJB   23.25
Supplier QWUSF  Japan   15          Product KSZOI   15.50
Supplier XYZ    Japan   NULL            NULL    NULL
```

Output 2 -

```
supplier,country,productid,productname,unitprice
Supplier GQRCV,Australia,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier JNNES,Australia,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier UNAHG,Brazil,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier ERVYZ,Canada,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier OGLRK,Canada,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier XOXZA,Denmark,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier ELCRN,Finland,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier ZRYDZ,France,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier OAVQT,France,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier LVJUA,France,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier ZPYVS,Germany,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier SVIYA,Germany,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier TEGSC,Germany,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier KEREV,Italy,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier ZWZDM,Italy,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier XYZ,Japan,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier QWUSF,Japan,13,Product POXFU,6.00
Supplier QWUSF,Japan,14,Product PWCJB,23.25
Supplier QWUSF,Japan,15,Product KSZOI,15.50
Supplier QOVFD,Japan,9,Product AOZBW,97.00
Supplier QOVFD,Japan,10,Product YHXGE,31.00
Supplier QOVFD,Japan,74,Product BKAZJ,10.00
Supplier FNUXM,Netherlands,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier NZLIF,Norway,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier CIYNM,Singapore,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier EQPNC,Spain,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier QQYEU,Sweden,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier QZGUF,Sweden,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier BWGYE,UK,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier SWRXU,UK,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier VHQZD,USA,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier STUAZ,USA,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier JDNUG,USA,NULL,NULL,NULL
Supplier UHZRG,USA,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: Is there some online place where I can store these outputs or maybe recreate my DB ? I want to be able to reference it here instead of making my question look too big, even when its actually very small.

Comment: Check [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL join: where clause vs. on clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` brings back every record from the 'LEFT' table, unless you limit it, as you did with your `WHERE` criteria.

When you change it to be part of the `JOIN` criteria it's not limiting the results, just limiting which records have non NULL values from the right table.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing Left join it always returns everything in the first table (Production.Suppliers).

In the first example the Where clause filters the Suppliers table to just show 'Japan'.
The query is something like:

> "Give me all the suppliers **that are in** Japan and show me their products"

When you do a join you are adding conditions to the table you are joining to (Production.Products). Because it's a left join you will ge all of the suppliers back, and only the products that have suppliers that are in Japan. You are saying something like:

> "Give me **all** the suppliers, and give me all the **products where the supplier is in Japan**"

It's a subtle difference but a very important one with regard to left joins.

If it was an `inner join` instead of a `left join` then you wouldn't have this problem, but you would be asking a different question again:

> "Give me all of the suppliers that **have** products in japan"

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the ON treats the part after the AND as a condition to the JOIN, so it returns NULL for the results from P if the condition is not met.

You should almost never put a condition on a join which does not use the table in the join (in this case, you are joining P, but applying a condition on the join which only references S).

Comment: Well, if the condition applied only to the outer table, you *do* want that in the join condition. Putting it in the where clause effectively turns your outer join to an inner join.