# Yii2 : Can I bind an array to an IN() condition in join?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, sql-injection

I will try below query, but not sure is prevent sql injection?

```
        $status = [1, 2, 3];
        $param = implode(', ', $status);

        $rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select('*')
            ->from('user')
            ->leftJoin('post', "post.user_id = user.id AND post.some_column = $value AND post.status IN ($param)");
            ->all();
```

> return expected results but may be occur sql injection. My IN condition look like is `IN (1, 2, 3)`

```
        $rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select('*')
            ->from('user')
            ->leftJoin('post', "post.user_id = user.id AND post.some_column = :sid AND post.status IN (:param)", [':param' => $param, ':sid' => $value]);
            ->all();
```

> only compare first element in array because is look like this `IN ('1, 2, 3')` its consist single string not check second element in array only work on first element.

I refer below link but no idea for how to implement this condition.

[Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Please give the solution for how to use `IN() Condition` in `On` part of join(PDO/Yii2/mysql).

Comment: Ok, I deleted my answer because `where` conditions are diff of `on` conditions and you need `on` conditions. By the way, I open this issue, may you are interested: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/11827

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/11827):

```php
        $rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select('*')
        ->from('user')
        ->leftJoin('post', ['post.user_id' => new \yii\db\Expression('user.id'), 'post.some_column' => $sid, 'post.status' => $statuesArray]);
        ->all();
```

Comment: I am using `MSSQL` . How can I pass my connection name in `(new \yii\db\Query())`

Comment: @Moeez, if it is different of `db`, you generally will pass it as a param of `all()`, `one()`and similar methods of your query. You can see the docs: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#all()-detail

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 can create a parametrized IN condition by passing the condition as an array i.e:

```
['post.status' => $status]
```

However, converting your join condition to the array format will not work as explained in the [Yii guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#join()-detail):

> Note that the array format of `where()` is designed to match columns to values instead of columns to columns, so the following would not work as expected: `['post.author_id' => 'user.id']`, it would match the post.author_id column value against the string `'user.id'`. It is recommended to use the string syntax here which is more suited for a join:
>
> `'post.author_id = user.id'`

Since you are using an `INNER JOIN` the result of putting the join condition in `WHERE` instead of in `ON` will be syntactically equal as explained in [INNER JOIN condition in WHERE clause or ON clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196223/inner-join-condition-in-where-clause-or-on-clause). For [readability and ease of maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019006/428543), you can leave the comparison for the tables columns in the join condition:

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select('*')
        ->from('user')
        ->innerJoin('post', 'post.user_id = user.id')
        ->where(['post.some_column' => $value, 'post.status' => $status])
        ->all();
```

Comment: sorry, I have used `leftJoin` in my project.  I have write query in my question is just demo. I used this same situation in my project. how to used `IN()` on `OnCondition`?