# Rails includes() LEFT OUTER JOIN with custom ON clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, rails-activerecord

In my scenario, I have a `BlogPost` model that `has_and_belongs_to_many :categories`. I want to filter *out* Blog Posts that belong to specific Categories, while still allowing for uncategorized Blog Posts (hence the need for a LEFT OUTER JOIN).

I expected this to work:

```
BlogPost.active.includes(:categories).where.not(categories: { id: [1, 2, 3] })
```

But it doesn't filter correctly because it puts the conditions at the end of the query, outside the LEFT OUTER JOIN (see this SO question / answer for the reason: [SQL join: where clause vs. on clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause?answertab=active#tab-top))

---

This works, but it is ugly:

```
BlogPost.active.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN blog_posts_categories
      ON blog_posts_categories.blog_post_id = blog_posts.id
      AND blog_posts_categories.category_id NOT IN(1, 2, 3)")
```

---

Is there an ActiveRecord-friendly way to add conditionals to the ON clause of a LEFT OUTER JOIN without manually typing it out the way I did?

Comment: If you want to filter out the blog posts, why are you using a LEFT JOIN or `includes`?  Why not a standard JOIN (`joins`)?

Comment: @PinnyM a standard JOIN won't work for me because I need the query to return BlogPosts that may not be tagged with any Categories

Comment: @ncherro it will take automatically once you mention the primary key and foreign key in association.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work.

```
BlogPost.active.joins(:categories).merge(Category.where.not(categories: { id: [1,2,3] })
```

and add it together with a scope that gets all the blogposts without a category.  Another thought would be to instead use a `has_many through` relationship, and actually create a model for `BlogPostCategory` as you can add intermediate scopes on it.

Comment: Thanks, but your first suggestion produces an INNER JOIN, which doesn't work for me. I hadn't thought about converting it to a `has_many_through` relationship. I'll reply again if that works

Comment: There is also [`left_outer_joins`](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/left_outer_joins) on is: `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods`, so maybe you're looking for `BlogPost.active.left_outer_joins(:categories).merge(Category.where.not(categories: { id: [1,2,3] })`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not thoroughly familiar with ActiveRecord syntax, but can you extend the filter to include rows where category_id `IS NULL`? That will satisfy your requirement.