# HQL: Why would one ever use WHERE instead of ON...AND in a JOIN statement?

Tags: sql, hive, hql

Suppose I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.column1,
a.column2,
b.column3
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b
ON a.column1 = b.column2
AND a.column2 = "value"
AND b.column3 = "other value"
```

Why would one ever use a WHERE when filtering the values rather than another AND, i.e.

```
SELECT a.column1,
a.column2,
b.column3
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b
ON a.column1 = b.column2
AND a.column2 = "value"
WHERE b.column3 = "other value"
```

Wouldn't AND always make the query faster, as it will filter out the data before the join?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there won't be any measurable **performance** difference between both the queries.

Personally i prefer to keep the Join conditions in `ON` clause and the filtering conditions in `Where` clause.

If you keep the filtering condition's in `where` clause it will be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Modern rdbms query optimizers do a great job at building efficient execution plans, compare the execution plans created by your two queries, they are identical. So there will not be a performance difference.

You may find older folk who suggest there's a performance increase when adding filtering criteria to a `JOIN` because `FROM` is evaluated before `WHERE`, thus filtering records earlier in the process and saving time.  This is just an artifact from old databases.

I agree with NoDisplayName, I usually put filtering criteria that references 1 side of the `JOIN` in the `WHERE` clause, unless needed as is sometimes the case with outer joins.

Answer (score 0):

Hive only supports equi-joins.
So in the ON clause you can only do equality comparison:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  ... a
JOIN
  ... b
ON
  a.column1 = b.column2
  AND a.column2 = "value"
```

But not:

```
ON
  a.column1 = b.column2
  a.column2 LIKE "value"
```

But you can do:

```
ON
  a.column1 = b.column2
WHERE
  a.column2 LIKE "value"
```