# what is the difference between using filter condition in WHERE clause and JOIN condition

Tags: sql

Say i have following Join query with any of join type (INNER/LEFT/RIGHT/FULL)

```
SELECT E.id, D.name, E.sal from EMP E
INNER/LEFT/RIGHT/FULL JOIN DEP D
ON E.id = D.id
AND E.sal > 100
```

Also, I have similar query with WHERE condition

```
SELECT E.id, D.name, E.sal from EMP E
INNER/LEFT/RIGHT/FULL JOIN DEP D
ON E.id = D.id
WHERE E.sal > 100
```

The only difference in above query is using E.sal > 100 in JOIN and WHERE Conditions.

**In which case above query will result differently ?** or both are same always ?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Thanks. Could you also please answer this question ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an `INNER JOIN`, there is no difference, either in terms of performance or the definition of the result set.  There is a difference with `OUTER JOIN`s.

The `WHERE` clause filters the results of the `FROM` *after* the `FROM` is evaluated.  So, consider these two queries:

```
SELECT E.id, D.name, E.sal
from EMP E LEFT JOIN
     DEP D
     ON E.id = D.id
WHERE E.sal > 100;

SELECT E.id, D.name, E.sal
from EMP E LEFT JOIN
     DEP D
     ON E.id = D.id AND E.sal > 100;
```

The first filters the `EMP` table to get the appropriate ids.  The second *does not* filter the `EMP` table.  Why not?  Well, the definition of `LEFT JOIN` says to take all rows in the first table, regardless of whether the `ON` finds a matching record in the second table.  So, there is no filtering.

Now, consider this version:

```
SELECT E.id, D.name, E.sal
from EMP E RIGHT JOIN
     DEP D
     ON E.id = D.id
WHERE E.sal > 100;

SELECT E.id, D.name, E.sal
from EMP E RIGHT JOIN
     DEP D
     ON E.id = D.id AND E.sal > 100;
```

The first turns the `RIGHT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.  Why?  Because for non-matching rows, `E.sal` is `NULL` and fails the `WHERE`.  The second version keeps all departments, even those that have no employees matching the condition.  Note:  I (and others) much prefer left outer joins to right outer joins in terms of following the logic.  The logic for a *left* outer join is simple:  keep all rows in the first table.

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` combines these two situations.

Comment: Here's a fiddle showing examples of all:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a3572/1/7    I was thinking 'deposits' instead of 'departments' so used people's names, but the example still shows when they're different/same.