# Unable to join 3 tables properly

Tags: mysql, relational-algebra, natural-join

While understanding natural joins, I came across the query:

> Find the names of branches with customers who have an account in the bank and live in Harrison

The relational algebra expression from the book as follows:

[image]

Implementing the same with the query:

```
select distinct a.branch_name from depositor d, account a, customer where d.account_number=a.account_number and customer.customer_city='Harrison';
```

I get spurious tuples as follows:

```
+-------------+
| branch_name |
+-------------+
| Perryridge  |
| Downtown    |
| Brighton    |
| Redwood     |
| Mianus      |
| Round Hill  |
+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But the query must have returned only Brighton and Perryridge based on the schema as follows:

```
mysql> select * from account;
+----------------+-------------+---------+
| account_number | branch_name | balance |
+----------------+-------------+---------+
| A101           | Downtown    |     500 |
| A102           | Perryridge  |     400 |
| A201           | Brighton    |     900 |
| A215           | Mianus      |     700 |
| A217           | Brighton    |     750 |
| A222           | Redwood     |     700 |
| A305           | Round Hill  |     350 |
+----------------+-------------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from customer;
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| customer_name | customer_street | customer_city |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| Adams         | Spring          | Pittsfield    |
| Brooks        | Senator         | Brooklyn      |
| Curry         | North           | Rye           |
| Glenn         | Sand Hill       | Woodside      |
| Green         | Walnut          | Stamford      |
| Hayes         | Main            | Harrison      |
| Johnson       | Alma            | Palo Alto     |
| Jones         | Main            | Harrison      |
| Lindsay       | Park            | Pittsfield    |
| Smith         | North           | Rye           |
| Turner        | Putnam          | Stamford      |
| Williams      | Nassau          | Princeton     |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from depositor;
+---------------+----------------+
| customer_name | account_number |
+---------------+----------------+
| Hayes         | A102           |
| Johnson       | A101           |
| Johnson       | A201           |
| Jones         | A217           |
| Lindsay       | A222           |
| Smith         | A215           |
| Turner        | A305           |
+---------------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: As i see you didnt join _customer_ table in your Where clause

Comment: But I have all the 3 tables referred in the from clause @The

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt make join for *customer* table,  your query should be like this

```
Select a.branch_name 
From depositor d 
  Join account a
    on d.account_number=a.account_number 
  Join customer as c
    on d.customer_name  = c.customer_name 
Where c.customer_city='Harrison'
```

I dont know how to join *customer* table to *depositor* maybe by name or if you have some key just replace it and you will get your result.

How to make joins in where clause  [useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

Answer (score 2):

You might forget the link between depositor and customer.

```
depositor.customer_name = customer.customer_name
```

So the entire query should be :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.branch_name  
FROM depositor d, account a, customer  
WHERE d.account_number = a.account_number  
AND d.customer_name = customer.customer_name  
AND customer.customer_city='Harrison'
```

Result :

```
+-------------+
| branch_name |
+-------------+
| Perryridge  |
| Brighton    |
+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```