# Is there a performance difference or another reason to use this JOIN syntax?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have come across several stored procedures in our "legacy" code that have joins that look like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB
        INNER JOIN TableC ON TableC.TableBId = TableB.TableBId
    ON TableA.TableAId = TableB.TableAId
```

I would write this query differently, like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.TableAId = TableB.TableAId
INNER JOIN TableC ON TableB.TableBId = TableC.TableBId
```

The results are the same, but I find the second example to be much easier to follow, especially in situations where there are several joins.  Is there any advantage to writing `JOIN` statements with the `ON` clause "deferred" until after all of the joins have been specified, as in the first example?

Comment: Was the legacy code ported from Microsoft Access as some point in the past? If I remember correctly, Access had some screwy restriction that would push all the `ON` clauses to the end after all the `JOIN` clauses. There were also parentheses. It's been awhile, so I don't remember the exact syntax.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Thankfully, I'm not sure if it was ever in Access, but it wouldn't surprise me if it were.  I think I remember Access being weird like that.  Access.....*shudder*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, predicate order doesn't matter at all to how it's executed. You could put the ON predicates in a WHERE instead, or mix them at random, and end up with the same execution plan. While I'd tread lightly when rewriting code I don't fully understand, in your own code, you should definitely write the way that's readable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause. Per this question, your information is incorrect. Can you explain why you think your information is correct?

Comment: OK, I should clarify: in an INNER JOIN, where all predicates are ANDed together, predicate order doesn't matter. In this specific case, I'm pretty sure the parser would even put out a functionally identical abstract syntax tree. The AST might be different if the predicates were in the WHERE, but the execution plan wouldn't be, at least in T-SQL. I can't point to a source because it's not like I just read this somewhere; haven't read a book on SQL in over a decade.