# JOIN Clauses compared to WHERE Clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, where-clause

I get two different answers when I run the two following queries.  I would really like to know why.  Is it the LEFT JOIN?  Is it the order of operations?  Could this occur in other JOIN types?

First Query

```
SELECT
First_Name
, E.Employee_ID
, I.Employee_REF_ID
FROM Employee AS E
LEFT JOIN Incentives AS I
ON (E.Employee_ID = I.Employee_REF_ID)  AND (I.Employee_Ref_Id IS NOT NULL);
```

Output

```
1.  First_Name  Employee_ID Employee_REF_ID
2.  John    1   1
3.  John    1   1
4.  Michael 2   2
5.  Michael 2   2
6.  Roy 3   3
7.  Tom 4   NULL
8.  Jerry   5   NULL
9.  NULL    6   NULL
10. TestName1   7   NULL
11. Lname%  8   NULL
```

Second Query

```
SELECT
First_Name
, E.Employee_ID
, I.Employee_REF_ID
   FROM Employee AS E
LEFT JOIN Incentives AS I
ON (E.Employee_ID = I.Employee_REF_ID)  
WHERE I.Employee_Ref_Id IS NOT NULL;
```

Output

```
1.  First_Name  Employee_ID Employee_REF_ID
2.  John    1   1
3.  Michael 2   2
4.  Roy 3   3
5.  John    1   1
6.  Michael 2   2
```

Original code from http://narendra86.blogspot.com/2013/10/top-80-sql-query-interview-questions.html

Comment: better show us the sample data in the tables being joined.

Comment: A LEFT join will return NULL columns when there is no match to the join predicate. By adding a WHERE filter to check if a field from the left joined table is not NULL you've recreated an INNER JOIN and you may as well use that.

Comment: That's pretty astute. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JOIN` allows you to link the second table to the first based on the condition you set.

In your first query,
`LEFT JOIN` will give you all columns from joined table `NULL` if there's no matching.

In your second query, your `WHERE` clause has further removed those non-matching records so there's no records with `NULL`.

Would give you better explanation if you can provide sample data on your tables.

Answer (score 1):

Take this as an example:

```
declare @table1 table (emp_id int, name varchar(10))
declare @table2 table (emp_ref_id int, ref_name varchar(10))

insert into @table1 values (1, 'emp1'), (2, 'emp2'), (3, 'emp3')
insert into @table2 values (1, 'empref1'), (2, 'empref2')
```

This query:

```
select *
from @table1 t1
left join @table2 t2 on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_ref_id and t2.emp_ref_id is not null
```

returns:

```
emp_id  name    emp_ref_id  ref_name
1       emp1    1           empref1
2       emp2    2           empref2
3       emp3    NULL        NULL
```

But this query:

```
select *
from @table1 t1
left join @table2 t2 on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_ref_id
where t2.emp_ref_id is not null
```

returns:

```
emp_id  name    emp_ref_id  ref_name
1       emp1    1           empref1
2       emp2    2           empref2
```

The difference is that on the first query the `t2.emp_ref_id is not null` condition doesn't have an effect because it's a left join so even if the right table doesn't have a matching row, those columns will be returned as null. On the 2nd query the condition `t2.emp_ref_id is not null` is checked against what's returned from the query so it removes the rows with `null` emp_ref_id.

Another example:

```
declare @table1 table (emp_id int, name varchar(10))
declare @table2 table (emp_ref_id int, ref_name varchar(10), col3 varchar)

insert into @table1 values (1, 'emp1'), (2, 'emp2'), (3, 'emp3')
insert into @table2 values (1, 'empref1', 'a'), (2, 'empref2', null)

select *
from @table1 t1
left join @table2 t2 on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_ref_id and t2.col3 is not null
```

will return:

```
emp_id  name    emp_ref_id  ref_name    col3
1       emp1    1           empref1     a
2       emp2    NULL        NULL        NULL
3       emp3    NULL        NULL        NULL
```

If you use this query:

```
select *
from @table1 t1
left join @table2 t2 on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_ref_id
```

It returns:

```
emp_id  name    emp_ref_id  ref_name    col3
1       emp1    1           empref1     a
2       emp2    2           empref2     NULL
3       emp3    NULL        NULL        NULL
```

As you can see, since it's a left join, when you have the condition `and t2.col3 is not null` it just means the left join can't find a row to match with from @table2, but will still return the row from table2, with null values.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is different because of the way `Left join` is evaluated - having a condition in `ON` clause can give a different result than having the equivalent condition in the `WHERE` clause (when you have the `ON` clause - we get `NULL` in the right side when there is no match but in `WHERE` clause the rows are filtered out ).

Check this stackoverflow answer for more details - [SQL join: where clause vs. on clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

Answer (score -2):

You should use an ORDER BY clause to force the order that you want. For example:

```
SELECT
First_Name
, E.Employee_ID
, I.Employee_REF_ID
FROM Employee AS E
LEFT JOIN Incentives AS I
ON (E.Employee_ID = I.Employee_REF_ID)  AND (I.Employee_Ref_Id IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY First_Name ASC;
```

Comment: Not related to the question, ORDER BY not relevant to the Join predicate, which needs to be explained along with the term `deterministic`.