# Combining column data from 2 separate SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in columns from 2 separate tables I'm looking to match up and analyze the output, but I'm a complete noob so I'm not sure how to write it. I've searched the results here but I guess I'm not understanding the answers

So If you don't mind helping, here's what I can do so far. The ItemID is the same for each item

```
SELECT ItemID, Title FROM Listings 
SELECT ItemID, SKU FROM Inventory
```

I tried plugging in UNION between the statement but I get error;

> *Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the UNION operation.*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join: where clause vs. on clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use join, like this:

```
SELECT a.ItemID, a.Title, b.ItemID, b.SKU
FROM Listings as a inner join Inventory as b on (a.ItemID = b.ItemID)
```

Comment: That is awesome! Worked like a charm.
What is the significance of the a. b. how does SQL use them.

Comment: And what if I wanted to use a LIKE statement to only match SKU's that start with '%STK%' in the above answer

Comment: @Chuck then just add `where b.SKU like...`

Answer (score 1):

You want an inner join between the two tables. Try something like

```
SELECT Listings.ItemID, Listings.Title, Inventory.ItemID, Inventory.SKU
FROM Listings
INNER JOIN Inventory ON Listings.itemId = Inventory.itemId;
```