# Are these queries equivalent?

Tags: mysql

For example i have 2 queries:

1)

```
SELECT * FROM unit
INNER JOIN entity
WHERE unit.length = entity.length
```

2)

```
SELECT * FROM unit
INNER JOIN entity ON entity.length = unit.length
```

Are these queries equivalent?

Comment: yes, if first work. From my opinion first should be `SELECT * FROM unit, entity
WHERE unit.length = entity.length`, but this is terrible code style.

Comment: Dupe train : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause?rq=1..

Comment: Thanks to everyone, yes it is a duplicate, next time I will look more carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both the query will produce same result.