# SQL Query for getting album information knowing only the track_id

Tags: mysql, sql

Having a simple database table structure for three tables;

```
artist, album, tracks
```

where the table album has a foreign key, named **artist_id**, to a field named **id** in the artist table, and table tracks having a foreign key, named **album_id** to a field id in table **album**. 
The table tracks, do have a unique id for each record, named **track_id**, as well as a foreign key, album_id, to the albums table

How does a query look that selects artist and album information, from knowing only the track_id?

I tried the following, but it returns more than one record, which is not right.

```
SELECT *
FROM artist
INNER JOIN albums ON artist.id = albums.artist_id
INNER JOIN tracks ON tracks.track_id = '4021'
```

Something is obviously missing..

Comment: You should really use the `where` for limiting the data and the `on`s for the `join` should be joined.

Comment: Aren't the 'on's joined? If not, what do you mean by that?

Comment: The `on` is how the data is joined. The `where` is what data should be returned. From the manual: `Generally, the ON clause serves for conditions that specify how to join tables, and the WHERE clause restricts which rows to include in the result set.` - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use where to filter, and added a missing join specification

```
SELECT *
FROM
artist
    INNER JOIN
albums
    ON artist.id = albums.artist_id
    INNER JOIN 
tracks
    ON tracks.album_id=albums.id
where tracks.track_id = '4021'
```

Comment: it seems one can use 'AND' instead of the WHERE statement. What would be the difference?

Comment: with today engines, there will be no difference, they are smart enough to move it as needed. Just for readability reasons, I use it this way.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause

Comment: A follow up question, In the above query, two columns are returned with the same name; artist.id and album.id. Is there a simple way to get retruned column names prefixed with their table name?

Comment: Not sure about MySQL, in SQL-Server you need to type each field alias, or can be added dynamically, but it a new story.

Answer (score 0):

Missing  the condition for join tracks and albums ON `tracks.album_id = albums.id`

```
SELECT *
FROM artist
INNER JOIN albums ON artist.id = albums.artist_id
INNER JOIN tracks ON tracks.album_id = albums.id 
      and  tracks.track_id = '4021' AND
```