# Confusion about 'and' filter inside a join

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Can some explain what is the difference between these 2 queries in HiveQL. Basically I wanted to filter out the dates to be greater than 2017-05-01 from `table a`. The second query didn't give the result i expected but the first one did. I thought they were equivalent

```
select a.user_id
, b.user_id
, a.event_date
, b.event_date
, to_date(a.event_date)
from default.t1 as a
left join stage.t2 as b
on a.user_id = b.user_id
and a.event_date = b.event_date
where a.event_date >= '2017-05-01'
```

vs.

```
select a.user_id
, b.user_id
, a.event_date
, b.event_date
, to_date(a.event_date)
from default.t1 as a
left join stage.t2 as b
on a.user_id = b.user_id
and a.event_date = b.event_date
and a.event_date >= '2017-05-01'`
```

Comment: You are using a `left join`, so in the first query you are getting results where `b.event_date` could be null and then filter the final result....in the second you put the date condition in the join, so you ensure to get the right data first....that's what I understand, but, someone could get a better explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `left join` keeps all rows in the first table, regardless of whether or not the `on` clause evaluates to true.  When the `on` clause evaluates to true, then it also has all matching rows in the second table.  Otherwise, the columns from the second table are `NULL`.

As a consequence, a `left join` basically ignores any filtering conditions on the first table.  It is going to keep the rows from the first table regardless.

Actually, the situation is slightly more complicated.  If the `on` condition does not evaluate to true, then the columns from the second table are all `NULL`.  So, in the second query, when the dates don't match, the columns from `b` should be `NULL`.

What to do?

- Conditions on the first table in a `left join` should always go in the `where` clause.
- Conditions on the second table should always go in the `on` clause.

Comment: thanks for the tip on when to use filter in the `on` and `where` clause. I've always had trouble wrapping my head around that (can't visualize it in my head)

Answer (score 1):

I find similar question, the answer by @Sandeep Jindal is the best

[SQL join: where clause vs. on clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

a. WHERE clause: After joining. Records will be filtered after join has taken place.

b. ON clause - Before joining. Records (from right table) will be filtered before joining. This may end up as null in the result (since OUTER join).