# PostgreSQL ON vs WHERE when joining tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, inner-join

I have 2 tables `customer` and `coupons`, a customer may or may not have a `reward_id` assigned to, so it's a nullable column. A customer can have many coupons and coupon belongs to a customer.

```
+-------------+------------+
|   coupons   | customers  |
+-------------+------------+
| id          | id         |
| customer_id | first_name |
| code        | reward_id  |
+-------------+------------+
customer_id column is indexed
```

I would like to make a join between 2 tables.

My attempt is:

```
select c.*, cust.id as cust_id, cust.first_name as cust_name
from coupons c
join customer cust
on c.customer_id = cust.id and cust.reward_id is not null
```

However, I think there isn't an index on reward_id, so I should move `cust.reward_id is not null` in `where` clause:

```
select c.*, cust.id as cust_id, cust.first_name as cust_name
from coupons c
join customer cust
on c.customer_id = cust.id
where cust.reward_id is not null
```

I wonder if the second attempt would be more efficient than the first attempt.

Comment: Create the missing index instead of moving conditions around. The optimizer will move them anyway, if it sees a benefit from it.

Comment: @stickybit would the second query is a better choice assuming `reward_id` is indexed?

Comment: There is a detailed discussion on what would be the diff in terms of Joins and Joins with where https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3481

Comment: @Rizwan thanks for your comment, but my question is a little different which focuses on the additional condition on `ON` clause vs having the additional condition in `WHERE` clause, and both queries using `JOIN`

Comment: @tkhuynh  . . . They should have the same execution plan.

Comment: Both will result in exactly the same execution plan

Comment: @GordonLinoff so it means there is no differences in performance, am I right? I did a benchmark on the 2 queries, and I see the second one is slightly faster.

Comment: @tkhuynh . . . That may be due to caching effects.  Or if the difference is really small (say < 5%) then just random variation.

Comment: This is an easily found faq & clearly so.. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL JOIN - WHERE clause vs. ON clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

Comment: Learn basics of relational/SQL query optimization/implementation. These are trivially mapped to the same implementation by the simplest query engine. Also it would be helpful to think about why you think you have a reason to think your guesses are justified. (It's better when you say "I wonder", but "I wonder" isn't a question. However "efficient" doesn't mean anything in particular.)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you see the execution plan on your own. Add `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` before your select statement and execute both to see the differences.

Here's how:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select ...
```

What it does? It actually executes the select statement and gives you back the execution plan which was chosen by query optimizer. Without `ANALYZE` keyword it would only estimate the execution plan without actually executing the statement in the background.

Database won't use two indexes at one time, so having an index on `customer(id)` will make it unable to use index on `customer(reward_id)`. This condition will actually be treated as a filter condition which is correct behaviour.

You could experiment with performance of a partial index created as such: `customer(id) where reward_id is not null`. This would decrease index size as it would only store these customer id's for which there is a `reward_id` assigned.

I generally like to split the relationship/join logic from conditions applied and I myself put them within the `WHERE` clause because it's more visible in there and easier to read for future if there are any more changes.

I suggest you see for yourself the possible performance gain, because it depends on how much data there is and the possible low cardinality for `reward_id`. For example if most rows have this column filled with a value it wouldn't make that much of a difference as the index size (normal vs partial) would be almost the same.

Comment: I did use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see the performance of the 2 queries and I notice that with a large number of records the second query perform better. However I still want to confirm whether moving `cust.reward_id is not null` to `WHERE` clause would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

In a  PostgreSQL inner join, whether a filter condition is placed in the ON clause or the WHERE clause does not impact a query result or performance.

Here is a guide that explores this topic in more detail: https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/using-on-versus-where-clauses-to-combine-and-filter-data-in-postgresql-joins

Comment: Theoretically yes, but in practice the optimizer returns different plans. Basic example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673841/sql-join-in-postgresql-different-execution-plan-in-where-clause-than-in-on-cla Any insight you might have would be appreciated.