# SQL JOIN in PostgreSQL - Different execution plan in WHERE clause than in ON clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, where-clause, on-clause

We have a simple statement in PostgreSQL 11.9/11.10 or 12.5 where we can write the join with a WHERE-CLAUSE or with a ON-CLAUSE. The meaning is exactly the same and therefore the number of returned rows too - But we receive a different explain plan. With more data inside the tables one execution plan is getting really bad and we want to understand why PostgreSQL chooses different explain plans for this situation. Any ideas?

Let's create some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    t1_nr int8 NOT NULL,
    name varchar(60),
    CONSTRAINT t1_pk PRIMARY KEY (t1_nr)
);

INSERT INTO t1 (t1_nr, name) SELECT s, left(md5(random()::text), 10) FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) s; -- 1 million records

CREATE TABLE t2 (
    t2_nr int8 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT t2_pk PRIMARY KEY (t2_nr)
);

INSERT INTO t2 (t2_nr) SELECT s FROM generate_series(1, 10000000) s; -- 10 million records

CREATE TABLE t3 (
    t1_nr int8 NOT NULL,
    t2_nr int8 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT t3_pk PRIMARY KEY (t2_nr, t1_nr)
);

INSERT INTO t3 (t1_nr, t2_nr) SELECT (s-1)/10+1, s FROM generate_series(1, 10000000) s; -- 10 t2 records per t1 records --> 10 million records
```

Our Statement with fully analyzed statistics:

```
EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t3 t3
    JOIN t2 t2 ON t2.t2_nr = t3.t2_nr
    --AND t3.t1_nr = t1.t1_nr /* GOOD (using ON-CLAUSE) */
    WHERE t3.t1_nr = t1.t1_nr /* BAD (using WHERE-CLAUSE) */
)
LIMIT 1000
```

The explain plan with the "GOOD" row (ON-CLAUSE):

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Limit  (cost=0.00..22896.86 rows=1000 width=19) (actual time=0.028..4.801 rows=1000 loops=1)                                          |
  Buffers: shared hit=8015                                                                                                            |
  ->  Seq Scan on t1  (cost=0.00..11448428.92 rows=500000 width=19) (actual time=0.027..4.725 rows=1000 loops=1)                      |
        Filter: (SubPlan 1)                                                                                                           |
        Buffers: shared hit=8015                                                                                                      |
        SubPlan 1                                                                                                                     |
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.87..180.43 rows=17 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1000)                           |
                Buffers: shared hit=8008                                                                                              |
                ->  Index Only Scan using t3_pk on t3  (cost=0.43..36.73 rows=17 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1000)|
                      Index Cond: (t1_nr = t1.t1_nr)                                                                                  |
                      Heap Fetches: 1000                                                                                              |
                      Buffers: shared hit=4003                                                                                        |
                ->  Index Only Scan using t2_pk on t2  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1000)  |
                      Index Cond: (t2_nr = t3.t2_nr)                                                                                  |
                      Heap Fetches: 1000                                                                                              |
                      Buffers: shared hit=4005                                                                                        |
Planning Time: 0.267 ms                                                                                                               |
Execution Time: 4.880 ms                                                                                                              |
```

The explain plan with the "BAD" row (WHERE-CLAUSE):

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Limit  (cost=1166.26..7343.42 rows=1000 width=19) (actual time=16.888..75.809 rows=1000 loops=1)                                                             |
  Buffers: shared hit=51883 read=11 dirtied=2                                                                                                                |
  ->  Merge Semi Join  (cost=1166.26..3690609.61 rows=597272 width=19) (actual time=16.887..75.703 rows=1000 loops=1)                                        |
        Merge Cond: (t1.t1_nr = t3.t1_nr)                                                                                                                    |
        Buffers: shared hit=51883 read=11 dirtied=2                                                                                                          |
        ->  Index Scan using t1_pk on t1  (cost=0.42..32353.42 rows=1000000 width=19) (actual time=0.010..0.271 rows=1000 loops=1)                           |
              Buffers: shared hit=12                                                                                                                         |
        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.89..3530760.13 rows=9999860 width=8) (actual time=16.873..74.064 rows=9991 loops=1)                                     |
              Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                             |
              Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                            |
              Buffers: shared hit=51871 read=11 dirtied=2                                                                                                    |
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.87..2375528.14 rows=4166608 width=8) (actual time=0.054..14.275 rows=4309 loops=3)                                    |
                    Buffers: shared hit=51871 read=11 dirtied=2                                                                                              |
                    ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using t3_pk on t3  (cost=0.43..370689.69 rows=4166608 width=16) (actual time=0.028..1.495 rows=4309 loops=3)|
                          Heap Fetches: 12927                                                                                                                |
                          Buffers: shared hit=131 read=6                                                                                                     |
                    ->  Index Only Scan using t2_pk on t2  (cost=0.43..0.48 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=12927)                    |
                          Index Cond: (t2_nr = t3.t2_nr)                                                                                                     |
                          Heap Fetches: 12927                                                                                                                |
                          Buffers: shared hit=51740 read=5 dirtied=2                                                                                         |
Planning Time: 0.475 ms                                                                                                                                      |
Execution Time: 75.947 ms                                                                                                                                    |
```

Comment: Could you use the results from EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE) _your_query_ ?

Comment: You're missing an index on t3.t1_nr: create index on t3(t1_nr); That has a massive impact on performance. I don't know why the query plans are (so) different

Comment: After ANALYZE the plans would be identical, I expect. And adding FOREIGN KEY constraints could also hint the planner.

Comment: @wildplasser: No it's not, at least not in version 12 where I'm testing. A simple join with all 3 tables, without the EXISTS gives me the best performance, about 5ms.

Comment: I guess the planner has fewer options to choose from. (pull up vs push down)

Comment: `SET parallel_tuple_cost = 1;` will result in identical plans. in pg-11.3 (the default appears to be 0.1)

Comment: Same on 13.1 (thanks for the script). Sounds like an optimizer bug.

Comment: Strange: pg-11.6 on one of my Raspberrys doesn't need the `SET parallel_tuple_cost = 1;` It gives identical (fast) plans.

Comment: `LIMIT 1000` without `ORDER BY` is not deterministic. Performance tests may be misleading as Postgres is free to return *any* 1000 rows, and may encounter different costs depending on that. Please retry with an added `ORDER BY` in the outer `SELECT`. I would expect the difference to go away.

Comment: There is something special about the outer query anyway. Since the conditions cannot be pulled up or pushed down, it is very imperative. In your case: it will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your ideas, if we add an index like

```
CREATE INDEX t3_t1_nr ON t3(t1_nr);
```

the "BAD"-Statement will improve a little bit.

But the final solution for us was to increase the statistics gathered for this tables:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ALTER COLUMN t1_nr SET STATISTICS 10000;
ALTER TABLE t2 ALTER COLUMN t2_nr SET STATISTICS 10000;
ALTER TABLE t3 ALTER COLUMN t1_nr SET STATISTICS 10000;

ANALYZE t1;
ANALYZE t2;
ANALYZE t3;
```

After this change both SELECTs has more about the same exection time.
More information can be found here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/planner-stats.html