# Understanding 'include' when resolving source association from target in sequelize and apollo-server

Tags: sequelize.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am writing a resolver (using sequelize) for my apollo-server and am struggling to understand how the resolve of this backwards association works... I am super confused with how the `include` in my sequelize query is working.

my model associations:

```
User.hasOne(models.Profile)  <- so the foreign key 'userId' is on the profile table

Profile.belongsTo(models.User) <- foreign key 'userId' still on profile table
```

my graphql schema:

```
type Profile {
  id: ID!
  user: User!
}
```

my resolver: (I can't query the `User` model using `where: {profileId: profile.id}` as the `profileId` foreign key doesn't exist on `User`) so... I use include..

```
Profile: {
  user: async (profile, _args, { models }) => {
    return await models.User.findOne({
      include: [{
        model: models.Profile,
        where: { id: profile.id } <- this makes zero sense to me.. id is the id of the Profile row? how does this work??
      }]
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `include` option, you are **eagerly loading** the specified associated model. From the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#eager-loading):

> When you are retrieving data from the database there is a fair chance that you also want to get associations with the same query - this is called eager loading.

When you `include` an associated model, under the hood Sequelize attaches a join statement to the query it generates. By default, this is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. That means if you write:

```
User.findAll({ include: [{ model: Profile }] })
```

The resulting query will find all Users. If a user happens to have a Profile, the relevant row in the result will also include the profile fields. On the other hand, we can force the join to be an `INNER JOIN` by adding the `required` option:

```
User.findAll({ include: [{ model: Profile, required: true }] })
```

Because it's an `INNER JOIN`, the resulting query returns **only** Users that have a Profile.

When you add a `where` inside the `include`, the JOIN is automatically converted to an `INNER JOIN` (unless you explicitly set `required` to `false`). The where clause itself actually becomes part of the `ON` statement of the `INNER JOIN`. So if we write:

```
User.findAll({ include: [{ model: Profile, where: { id: 'someId' } }] })
```

the results will include all Users that have a Profile **and** where that profile's id is equal to `someId`. The `where` is always specific to the model we're including, so there's no need to specify which model's `id` field we're interested in.

Lastly, if use `findOne` instead of `findAll`, Sequelize simply adds a `LIMIT` of 1 to the query and the method resolves to a single instance of the Model instead of an array.

A complete discussion of joins is outside the scope of this question. You can check out these other questions for more details:

- [What is the difference between “INNER JOIN” and “OUTER JOIN”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)
- [SQL join: where clause vs. on clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)