# Raw SQL and generate_series in Rails Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Not sure what to name title for this, but I have a difficult time rewriting raw SQL to Rails ActiveRecord methods.

I want to extract sum(total) of transactions by each month in the date range that is chosen.

**NOTE**: all months that are in that range needs to be shown. 
For that I'm using `generate_series` SQL method to generate series of months in that range.

The method I'm writing is in the Query object that has an existing relation that is filtered transactions from before.

**My functions for now:**

```
  def group_total_by_months
   @relation.joins("RIGHT JOIN generate_series(TIMESTAMP '1-1-2018', TIMESTAMP '1-1-2020', interval '1 month') AS series
                     ON date_trunc('month', transactions.payment_date) = series")
            .group("series")
            .select("series AS payment_date, sum(transactions.total) AS total")
  end
```

**Result:**

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Transaction id: nil, total: 0.61173e3, payment_date: "2019-06-01 00:00:00">, #<Transaction id: nil, total: 0.364446e4, payment_date: "2019-10-01 00:00:00">, #<Transaction id: nil, total: 0.1625e4, payment_date: "2019-08-01 00:00:00">]>
```

This is sumed total by months, but only months that exist in transactions. Why? Because generated SQL looks like this and FROM clause is from all transactions, not filtered ones:

```
    SELECT series AS payment_date, sum(transactions.total) AS total FROM \"transactions\" 
RIGHT JOIN generate_series(TIMESTAMP '1-1-2018', TIMESTAMP '1-1-2020', interval '1 month') AS series\n    ON date_trunc('month', transactions.payment_date) = series 
WHERE \"transactions\".\"account_id\" = 1 
GROUP BY series
```

I **need SQL that looks like this**:

```
WITH filteret_transactions AS (
    SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE transactions.account_id = 1
)

 SELECT series AS payment_date, sum(filteret_transactions.total) AS total 
    FROM  filteret_transactions
  RIGHT JOIN generate_series(TIMESTAMP '1-1-2018', TIMESTAMP '1-1-2020', interval '1 month') AS series
  ON date_trunc('month', filteret_transactions.payment_date) = series GROUP BY series
```

How can I achive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the condition before the joining happens. You can pass the needed params as arguments and do the query as you did in the first approach. I have added the condition in the joining itself(you can add more if needed) and used the model itself(Transaction) to joining.

```
def group_total_by_months(account_id: )
   Transaction.joins("RIGHT JOIN generate_series(TIMESTAMP '1-1-2018', TIMESTAMP '1-1-2020', interval '1 month') AS series
                     ON date_trunc('month', transactions.payment_date) = series AND transactions\".\"account_id\" = #{account_id}")
            .group("series")
            .select("series AS payment_date, sum(transactions.total) AS total")
end
```

**EDIT**: possible solution(but won't work with all situations)

You can get the applied where conditions with this method(https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/where_values_hash). create a query condition and use it in the raw query.

```
def group_total_by_months

  applied_conditions = []

  @transation.where_values_hash.each do |p|
    applied_conditions << "AND #{p.first} = #{p.second}"
  end

  Transaction.joins("RIGHT JOIN generate_series(TIMESTAMP '1-1-2018', TIMESTAMP '1-1-2020', interval '1 month') AS series
                         ON date_trunc('month', transactions.payment_date) = series #{applied_conditions.join(' ')}")
                .group("series")
                .select("series AS payment_date, sum(transactions.total) AS total")
 end
```

**NOTE**

```
>> Project.where(id: 12).where_values_hash
>>  {"id"=>12}
>> Project.where('id = 12').where_values_hash
>> {}
```

Ref: [SQL join: where clause vs. on clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

Comment: Thanks, @Aarthi, I'm really sad there id no other way to use `@relation`. I thought I don't know enough ActiveRecord and don't know how to do it with existing @relation.

Comment: Can you share how you initialize `@relation`

Comment: Ofcourse, this is with date range and input kind, `inputs  = GroupedTransactionsQuery.new(relation:  current_user.account.transactions.inputs.from_date(@start_date).to_date(@start_date))`  and inside query object initalizer:    `@relation   = params[:relation] || Transaction.all`

Comment: I have updated answer and that is only a possible solution which doesn't work in some cases(added that in the note)