# SQL LEFT JOIN: difference between WHERE and condition inside AND

Tags: sql, left-join, where-clause

What's the difference between

```
select t.*,
a.age
from t
left join a
on t.ID = a.ID and a.column > 10
```

and

```
select t.*,
a.age
from t
left join a
on t.ID = a.ID
where a.column > 10
```

?
Specifically, what's the difference when I put the condition on the table I am joining to the main table inside `AND` versus inside `WHERE` condition?

Comment: Good question. Create the tables, add some sample data and run the queries!

Comment: The second one is effectively an inner join

Comment: The important distinction is that with the `LEFT JOIN` condition, you filter out non-matching rows before joining the two tables together, thus only joining to matching rows

Comment: you miss the `FROM` in your examples :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL join: where clause vs. on clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with a `left join` there is a difference

with condition on `left join` rows with `column > 10` will be there filled with nulls

with `where` condition rows will be filtered out

with a `inner join` there is no difference

example:

```
declare @t table (id int, dummy varchar(20))
declare @a table (id int, age int, col int)

insert into @t
select * from (
values 
    (1, 'pippo'    ),
    (2, 'pluto'    ),
    (3, 'paperino' ),
    (4, 'ciccio'   ),
    (5, 'caio'     ),
    (5, 'sempronio')
) x (c1,c2)

insert into @a
select * from (
values 
    (1, 38, 2 ),
    (2, 26, 5 ),
    (3, 41, 12),
    (4, 15, 11),
    (5, 39, 7 )
) x (c1,c2,c3)

select t.*, a.age
from @t t
left join @a a on t.ID = a.ID and a.col > 10
```

Outputs:

```
id  dummy       age
1   pippo       NULL
2   pluto       NULL
3   paperino    41
4   ciccio      15
5   caio        NULL
5   sempronio   NULL
```

While

```
select t.*, a.age
from @t t
left join @a a on t.ID = a.ID
where a.col > 10
```

Outputs:

```
id  dummy       age
3   paperino    41
4   ciccio      15
```

So with `LEFT JOIN` you will get **ALWAYS** all the rows from 1st table

If the join condition is true, you will get columns from joined table filled with their values, if the condition is false their columns will be `NULL`

With `WHERE` condition you will get only the rows that match the condition.

Comment: What do you mean by "with condition on left join rows with column > 10 will be there filled with nulls"? I still cannot imagine it.

Answer (score 0):

So what's the difference between them?

An explanation through examples:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Students
> (
>   StudentId INT PRIMARY KEY,
>   Name VARCHAR(100)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Scores
> (
>   ScoreId INT PRIMARY KEY,
>   ExamId INT NOT NULL,
>   StudentId INT NOT NULL,
>   Score DECIMAL(4,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
>   FOREIGN KEY (StudentId) 
>     REFERENCES Students(StudentId)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Students
> (StudentId, Name) VALUES
> (11,'Joe Shmoe'),
> (12,'Jane Doe'),
> (47,'Norma Nelson');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Scores
> (ScoreId, ExamId, StudentId, Score) VALUES
> (1, 101, 11, 65.2),
> (2, 101, 12, 72.6),
> (3, 102, 11, 69.6);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Using an INNER JOIN
> --
> -- Only Students that have scores
> -- So only when there's a match between the 2 tables
> --
> SELECT stu.Name, sco.Score
> FROM Students AS stu
> INNER JOIN Scores AS sco
>   ON sco.StudentId = stu.StudentId
> ORDER BY stu.Name
> ```
>
> ```
> Name      | Score
> :-------- | :----
> Jane Doe  | 72.6 
> Joe Shmoe | 65.2 
> Joe Shmoe | 69.6
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Using an LEFT JOIN
> --
> -- All Students, even those without scores
> -- Those that couldn't be matched will show NULL's
> -- for the fields from the joined table
> --
> SELECT stu.Name, sco.Score, sco.ScoreId
> FROM Students AS stu
> LEFT JOIN Scores AS sco
>   ON sco.StudentId = stu.StudentId
> ORDER BY stu.Name
> ```
>
> ```
> Name         | Score | ScoreId
> :----------- | :---- | :------
> Jane Doe     | 72.6  | 2      
> Joe Shmoe    | 65.2  | 1      
> Joe Shmoe    | 69.6  | 3      
> Norma Nelson | null  | null
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Using an LEFT JOIN
> -- But with an extra criteria in the ON clause
> --
> -- All Students again.
> -- That have scores >= 66
> -- But also the unmatched without scores
> -- 
> SELECT stu.Name, sco.Score, sco.ScoreId
> FROM Students AS stu
> LEFT JOIN Scores AS sco
>   ON sco.StudentId = stu.StudentId
>
>  AND sco.Score >= 66.0
>
> ORDER BY stu.Name
> ```
>
> ```
> Name         | Score | ScoreId
> :----------- | :---- | :------
> Jane Doe     | 72.6  | 2      
> Joe Shmoe    | 69.6  | 3      
> Norma Nelson | null  | null
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Using an LEFT JOIN
> -- But with an extra criteria in the WHERE clause
> --
> -- Only students with scores >= 66
> -- The WHERE filters out the unmatched.
> -- 
> SELECT stu.Name, sco.Score
> FROM Students AS stu
> LEFT JOIN Scores AS sco
>   ON sco.StudentId = stu.StudentId
>
> WHERE sco.Score >= 66.0
>
> ORDER BY stu.Name
> ```
>
> ```
> Name      | Score
> :-------- | :----
> Jane Doe  | 72.6 
> Joe Shmoe | 69.6
> ```

> ```
> --
> -- Using an INNER JOIN
> -- And with an extra criteria in the WHERE clause
> --
> -- Only Students that have scores >= 66
> --
> SELECT stu.Name, sco.Score
> FROM Students AS stu
> INNER JOIN Scores AS sco
>   ON sco.StudentId = stu.StudentId
> WHERE sco.Score >= 66
> ORDER BY stu.Name
> ```
>
> ```
> Name      | Score
> :-------- | :----
> Jane Doe  | 72.6 
> Joe Shmoe | 69.6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=84951a4375829e506e9ced48280f0060)*

Did you notice how the criteria in the WHERE clause can make a `LEFT JOIN` behave like an `INNER JOIN`?