# Explain the difference between these two SQL Queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

First Query:

```
SELECT 
    d.id,
    d.brand_name,
    count(*) AS no_of_time_used
FROM content oc
LEFT JOIN drama d ON d.id = oc.drama_id
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.id = oc.order_id
    AND o.fundraiser_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY drama_id
ORDER BY no_of_time_used DESC;
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT 
    d.id,
    d.brand_name,
    count(*) AS no_of_time_used
FROM content oc
LEFT JOIN drama d ON d.id = oc.drama_id
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.id = oc.order_id
WHERE o.fundraiser_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY drama_id
ORDER BY no_of_time_used DESC;
```

There is only one difference in these queries that's **AND vs WHERE**. In First Query, I have used **AND** just after the second JOIN Statement whereas in the second query I have used **WHERE** in place of **AND**.

**Edit:**  Both Queries are returning different result.

Comment: When you use `AND` you are adding a second condition to the join. When you use `WHERE` you are adding a condition to the entire query. Totally different things. Even if they return the same results, they are not equivalent. BTW why have you tagged 4 RDBMS's?

Comment: @SushantYelpale are you sure? The second query will remove all rows where `o.fundraiser_id` is null. The first won't remove the rows, because its a left join.

Comment: @SushantYelpale It's not giving the same result.

Comment: @DaleK I am using MYSQL and you are correct results are different in both cases.

Comment: Would you mind providing a common sample input and separated output of both queries? I'm quite sure by doing this you will realise the difference. It being the second query presumably returns less rows than the first...

Comment: @LaurentS. You are correct my friend, second query is returning less records as compared to first one.

Comment: In 2nd query the last join is really inner, not left.

Comment: The stated duplicate IS NOT a duplicate of this question.  For instance, the OP is clear that the two versions return different results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause because both questions ask what the difference is if a condition is within the where clause vs if it is in the on clause.

Comment: @Shadow . . . No.  This question is about a specific filtering condition and how that affects the results.  It is has nothing to do with putting `JOIN` conditions in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Any condition in the on clause is a join condition. This question is as you wrote, a specific example of the generic question about putting conditions in the on vs where clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question here is the condition on `o.fundraiser_id IS NOT NULL`.

In your the query, the condition is in the `ON` clause:

```
FROM content oc LEFT JOIN
     drama d
     ON d.id = oc.drama_id LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON o.id = oc.order_id AND
        o.fundraiser_id IS NOT NULL
```

This is saying to keep all the rows in `content` regardless of whether there is a match in `orders`.  That is, the number of rows does not decrease (relative to not using the `LEFT JOIN orders`).

However, this affects the *columns* from `orders`.  Only rows with a non-`NULL` `fundraiser_id` are in the result set.  If there are no such values, then for that `order_id` the columns are `NULL`.

The second form is the much more typical form:

```
FROM content oc LEFT JOIN
     drama d
     ON d.id = oc.drama_id LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON o.id = oc.order_id
WHERE o.fundraiser_id IS NOT NULL
```

The intention here *does* filter out rows.  It will filter out rows where `fundraiser_id` is not `NULL`.  A `NULL` value can appear in two ways:

- The value could be `NULL` in `orders`.
- The `LEFT JOIN` might find no matching `order`.

This version *filters* out these rows, so it changes the number of rows.  At the very least, it turns the second `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.