# MySql SELECT * FROM Table A and JOIN Column FROM Table B WHERE LOG_ID Match

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, inner-join

I need SQL Query i mention details in sample image, I hope you understand

Thank you

[image: Sample IMG]

Comment: s_id is 101 but the log id and results are 102. The results don't match.

Comment: sorry for my mistake i correct that now

Comment: Why `log_id=101` are not included into the output?

Comment: Please share more details. What's your question? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: i need only records where log_id="102"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query and let us know if it works for you:-

> Select a.*, b.degree from table_a as a inner join table_b as b on
> b.log_id=a.log_id order by a.log_id asc

In this database query we have performed an inner join between the two tables and matched it based on log_id and at last order it in ascending order based on log_id itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this code works but its return full data i need records only where log id = 102

Comment: @Haja I've provided the `log_id` filter in my answer.

Comment: Select a.*, b.degree from table_a as a inner join table_b as b on b.log_id=a.log_id where a.log_id="102" order by a.log_id asc;

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.*, b.degree
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.s_id = b.n_id
WHERE a.log_id = 102
ORDER BY a.log_id ASC;
```

Remember to change the table names `a` and `b` to the correct table names. More on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause).

Comment: Thanks for your reply larry..... Select a.*, b.degree from table_a as a inner join table_b as b on b.log_id=a.log_id where a.log_id="102" order by a.log_id asc;  this code works for me

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

Select a.*, b.degree from table_a as a inner join table_b as b on b.log_id=a.log_id where a.log_id="102" order by a.log_id asc;

Thanks you all

Comment: Glad you got the right solution, next time try to provide more information, please.