# Laravel eloquent double join returning empty

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a laravel eloquent db query that I would like to return results based on chained join.

```
$replies = DB::table('model_replies')
                                ->join('support_tickets', function($join){
                                        $join->on('model_replies.model_id', '=', 'support_tickets.id');
                                        $join->where('model_replies.model', '=', DB::raw('"SupportTicket"'));
                                        })
                                ->join('produce_requests', function($join){
                                        $join->on('model_replies.model_id', '=', 'produce_requests.id');
                                        $join->where('model_replies.model', '=', DB::raw('"ProduceRequest"'));
                                        })

                                ->get();
```

I followed the [example from the docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses).

The problem is when I chain the join statements as [suggested here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#inner-join-clause) my query gives no results.

A single join works just fine. But I need to be able to chain several of them.

[image: Double join not working]

What could I be doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Update, I updated the join statement to this: `->join('produce_requests', function($join){
                                        $join->on('model_replies.model_id', '=', 'produce_requests.id')
                                        ->where('model_replies.model', "ProduceRequest");
                                        })` by removing the `$join` on `where` as it is in the docs but still nothing changed.

Comment: shouldn't your `$join->where` be `$join->on`? Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause

Comment: @SumitWadhwa `$join->on` gives same result.

Comment: did you try `->leftJoin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly. You want to get `support_tickets` for those `model_replies` where `model_replies.model = SupportTicket`

```
DB::table('model_replies')
     ->leftJoin('support_tickets', function($join){
          $join->on('model_replies.model_id', '=', 'support_tickets.id');
          $join->on('model_replies.model', '=', DB::raw('"SupportTicket"'));
      })
      ->leftJoin('produce_requests', function($join){
          $join->on('model_replies.model_id', '=', 'produce_requests.id');
          $join->where('model_replies.model', '=', DB::raw('"ProduceRequest"'));
       })
       ->get();
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the third argument for $join->on is considered to be a column binding. Even if I do replace that with `DB::raw('"SupportTicket"')` I still get same result. I can't use two joins.

Comment: @KhaKali try with your code but with a `->leftJoin`

Comment: Thank you sir. I do appreciate your guidance.

Comment: @KhaKali you're welcome. the reason `->join` didn't work is because it's an inner join, but we needed every row from our main table `model_replies` hence the leftJoin

Comment: @sumit-wadhawa are you able to help me extend this? please check my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238956/laravel-multiple-leftjoin-groupby-two-fileds-and-limit-results