# Why does a join with 'and' some clause differ from a join followed by 'where' that same clause

Tags: sql

I have two tables

**A**
*id, b_id*

and

**B**
*id, arbitrary_binary_value*

*arbitrary_binary_value* is really a field that is 1 or 0, each otherwise unique row is duplicated with a 1 and a 0, this is just some db I am working with

Anyway, I wrote a query

```
select * from a left join b on a.b_id = b.id
where b.arbitrary_binary_value = 0
```

and I thought it would yield the same number as

```
select * from a
```

but it did not,

so I changed query to

```
select * from a left join b on a.b_id = b.id
AND b.arbitrary_binary_value = 0
```

and it **did** yield the same number as the number of rows in a, as expected

Why did the where clause not behave as expected, when the and clause did?

Comment: Not helpful, I found the answer here though https://stackoverflow.com/a/20981676/2089889

Comment: The first one is also functionally equivalent to `SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id WHERE b.arbitrary_binary_value = 0` since placing a condition on the left table in the where clause causes an implicit INNER JOIN.