# Inner Join : Different Results with Filtering Condition in ON Clause v/s Where Clause

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I executed these Queries

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON coalesce(A.a1,'') = coalesce(B.a1,'') and A.a1 <> '';
                                                       /\
                                                       ||
                                              Condition in On Clause
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON coalesce(A.a1,'') = coalesce(B.a1,'') WHERE A.a1 <> '';
                                                       /\
                                                       ||
                                              Condition in Where Clause
```

and get different Result ?

I want to understand what is the Difference between putting filtering condition in **On** Clause vs Condition in **Where** claues ,

which one is better in terms of performance ?

**Update**

**Sample Data**

`a1` is blank `''` in both Tables .

```
Now with 1st Query i am getting no Rows --> 0 Rows

but with my 2nd Queries i am getting multiple Rows --> 1251 Rows
```

Comment: Those two queries are functionally equivalent. I'm guessing you've left something out of your question.

Answer (score 1):

They are not same.

Consider these queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN OrderLines ON OrderLines.OrderID=Orders.ID
WHERE Orders.ID = 12345
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN OrderLines ON OrderLines.OrderID=Orders.ID AND Orders.ID=12345
```

The first will return an order and its lines, if any, for order number 12345.  The second will return all orders, but only order 12345 will have any lines associated with it.

With an INNER JOIN, the clauses are *effectively* equivalent. However, just because they are functionally the same, in that they produce the same results, does not mean the two kinds of clauses have the same semantic meaning.

I meant:

-Does not matter for inner joins

-Matters for outer joins

a. 'where' clause: After joining. Records after join would be filtered.

b. 'on' clause - Before joining. Records (from right Table) would be filtered before joining, this may end up as null in the result (since OUTER join).

Please refer these articles:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/05/14/criteria-on-outer-joined-tables.aspx

and

https://sites.google.com/site/nosuchmethodexception/database/join/join-vs-where-clause

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219046/help-with-a-where-on-a-left-join-sql-query#219053 this too

Comment: Oh...
Can you post some of your sample data in post?

Comment: Sample Data Added , I know for Left Join , searching for Inner Join as per my understanding both queries in case of Inner Join should give me 0 Result

Comment: Yes...
Even am wondering :)
Let me too check in my local database

Comment: @Avidan To clarify, the first *is effectively* an inner join! In fact, from MySQL's point of view it *is* an inner join.

Comment: @NeerajJain I tried equivalent queries on my three different tables. They yield me same results for inner joins. :) What values your `a1` columns contain in both the tables ? and what is it's datatype?

Answer (score 0):

In your first query,  the condition " and A.a1<>'' " is applied only to table B. However, the where condition in your second query is applied to A and B.

It doesnt have any affect on Inner Join but it has affects ont Left Join

Comment: I am using Inner Join and i am getting different result . I know how it behaves on left and right join